# Poor network performance from KVM virtual machine

Tags: networking, kvm, file-transfer

I am running a 32-bit Linux virtual machine on KVM. The host machine is a 64-bit Linux machine connected to a LAN.  Attempting to transfer files with scp from the KVM machine to a server on the LAN gives abysmal performance, about 500kB/s over gigabit Ethernet.  Around 1% of the expected rate.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [virtio](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Virtio). It allows a direct connection between the VM and the host without the need to emulate (slow) hardware. I measured high network performance improvements with it.

For example, you can enable the virtio network device by the kvm command line parameter "-net nic,model=virtio".

If you are using the virtio block devices, please note that the new device names are then "vda1" etc., but this should be not a problem since current Linux distributions detect the partitions according to their UUIDs.

Comment: Wow!  Simply, wow!  Why is this not the default?  Note that specifying this option overrides the defaults, ``-net nic -net user``.  Remember to add ``-net user`` after the virtio option.

Comment: note for the future: virtio was default when I created the VM in virt-manager, but I had to change the MAC and for some reason, THAT defaults to `rtl` and not `virtio`. Maybe a bug?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem of the Disk I/O performance inside the guest. If you are using a disk image, few steps apply to have better performance :

Firs, you will have to play around with the `cache` option of the disk configuration of your guest.

> By default, writethrough caching is used for all block device.
>   This means that the host page cache will be used to read and write
>   data but write notification will be sent to the guest only when the
>   data has been reported as written by the storage subsystem.
>
> Writeback caching will report data writes as completed as soon as
>   the data is present in the host page cache. This is safe as long
>   as you trust your host. If your host crashes or loses power, then
>   the guest may experience data corruption. When using the -snapshot
>   option, writeback caching is used by default.
>
> The host page can be avoided entirely with cache=none. This will
>   attempt to do disk IO directly to the guests memory. QEMU may
>   still perform an internal copy of the data.
>
> Some block drivers perform badly with cache=writethrough, most
>   notably, qcow2. If performance is more important than correctness,
>   cache=writeback should be used with qcow2. By default, if no
>   explicit caching is specified for a qcow2 disk image,
>   cache=writeback will be used. For all other disk types,
>   cache=writethrough is the default.

Then, you will also have to play around with elevator option of the kernel : you will have to append `elevator=noop` at your grub linux command line like this :

```
# Edit your /etc/default/grub.conf (on Debian-based distribution)
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash elevator=noop"
```

A better explaination of this is available at : http://lonesysadmin.net/2008/02/21/elevatornoop/ ; but in a few words, the host linux kernel and the guest linux kernel both try to optimize I/O and it tends to be worse than anything for the guest (the guest should leave this task to the host).